# CGPS: GPS Timeout - Sierra Wireless

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, gps

I'm trying to setup a GPS on a computer that I've recently built.

Ubuntu 12.04.

GPS is from [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/products/960) connected to a Sierra MC7700 card which is connected to a MikroTik RB14eU.

Setup for the GPS was:

```
cat "options sierra nmea=1" > /etc/modprobe.d/sierra.conf
AT!ENTERCND="A710"
AT!UDPID=68A3
AT!RESET
dpkg-reconfigure gpsd
```

The GPS is then configured on ttyUSB2
Currently the GPS seems to be outputting data, but cgps is timing out, and gpsd is running.

If I do:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB2
```

then I get repeated:

```
$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
$GNGNS,,,,,,NN,,,,,,*53
$GPVTG,,T,,M,,N,,K,N*2C
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
$GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*00
$GPGGA,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,*66
$GNGNS,,,,,,NN,,,,,,*53
$GNGNS,,,,,,NN,,,,,,*53
*78
```

If I telnet to the device using `telnet localhost 2947` and input the `?WATCH={"enable":true,"json":true}` then I get the following, but nothing after that.

```
{"class":"DEVICES","devices":[{"class":"DEVICE","path":"/dev/ttyUSB5","activated":"2014-04-02T18:22:52.966Z","flags":1,"driver":"Generic NMEA","native":0,"bps":9600,"parity":"N","stopbits":1,"cycle":1.00}]}
{"class":"WATCH","enable":true,"json":true,"nmea":false,"raw":0,"scaled":false,"timing":false}
```

The only error I'm seeing is:

```
gpsd:SHOUT: vendor/product match with 091e:0003 not found
```

and

```
cgps: GPS timeout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the antenna that was purchased was only half of a GPS antenna.

The other half of the antenna was a 12"x12" sheet of metal. We had to attach the GPS device to the center of the metal to get the antenna to connect to the satellites.

No where in the documentation of the antenna could we find any information on this.